# How to set text in datetimepicker with ngx-mat-datetime-picker in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-daterangepicker

I am using the library ngx-mat-datetime-picker from angular-material-components to get datetime selection. It is working well so far, but I need to be able to set text in front of the hours and minutes, like 'HH' and 'MM'.

What I have is:

[image]

And what I am looking for is something like this:

[image]

Can someone help with that?

This is the code I have:

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="dateStart" placeholder="Date Start" [(ngModel)]="dS" disabled>
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #dateStart disabled="false"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using version **@angular-material-components/datetime-picker
@7.0.0** and this behavior is **included by default**, also you can use [stepHour], [stepSecond] and [stepMinute] attributes to control steps size

```html
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker
      [stepHour]="1" 
      [stepSecond]="10" 
      [stepMinute]="5" 
      [enableMeridian]="true">
</ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```